# Inferring opening/closing parens?

Tags: parsing, syntax, ide, parentheses

It seems like someone must have done work on figuring out how to infer or suggest where to put closing parentheses.  I mean, highlighting matching parens is great, but suggesting would be even better.  Is this a defined problem?  If so, what is its name (like, what should I Google Scholar?).  If not, why not?  Is it an obviously impossible/poorly posed question?

To wit, let's say I have some malformed, ruby code:

```
foo.all.map { |i| i.bar }).uniq.compact.reject { |j| j.match /baz/i }
```

Note that I'm missing the initial parenthesis.  The problem I'm talking about is, "How do I suggest the insertion of a paren at the beginning when I move my cursor over the unpaired paren?"

If this is not a poorly posed question, why hasn't someone done this yet?

Comment: Could you illustrate your idea with one or two examples of how such a suggestion would work?

Comment: There are editors/IDEs, for example Vim and Eclipse, which automatically add the closing parenthesis after you typed an opening parenthesis. But I'm sure this is not what you imagined :)

Comment: It's called operator precedence. And it's even better than what you describe, because it's formally defined (there's a definite operator precedence table for most languages), simple to follow and keep in your hand, and even infers the opening parenthesis as well.

Comment: Added example.  I'm not just talking about automatically closing an open paren, I'm talking about suggesting where to insert the closing paren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could keep track of "balanced" vs "unbalanced" parens as the user types. Then suggest a paren as soon as the parens become unbalanced.

For example typing `(something))` would suggest an opening paren before `s`. Correctly placing the "fix-it" paren might be challenging. For example if the user types `something(else))` there's a choice: insert the fix-it opening paren after `g` or at the beginning of the string?

Keeping track of balanced parens would be relatively simple:

```
int parenCount = 0

event keyUp(char c){
    if(c is close-paren){
        parenCount--;
    }else if(c is open-paren){
        parenCount++;
    }
    if(parenCount < 0){
        // missing an open-paren somewhere
    }
}

// handle missing close-parens when user finished typing the string...
// for example if user types "myObject.something(" and hits enter
```

Might also need to look for unnecessary parens as in `a.doSomethingWith((aNumber))`